# Why cant I get the value I have in a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

im using jquery and php to run the code. I simply get the values form the database and store then in a variable. Then I call the variable but the error is instead of the value a "#" is being output by the variable

The code is as follows

```
    <?php
$rooms = file_get_contents('API FUNCTION HERE');
$rooms = json_decode($rooms);

 foreach ($rooms->rooms as $room) {
    $room = (array)$room;   
    foreach($room as $key => $value){
        echo '<input type="hidden" id="room_num_'.$key.'" name="room_num_'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'">';
    }
 }
 ?>
<script>
    
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        t = setTimeout("checkColors()",1000);
        t = setTimeout("checkColors2()",1000);

            
    jQuery(".imp-shape").mouseleave(function(){
        t = setTimeout("checkColors()",100);
        t = setTimeout("checkColors2()",100);


    });
  });
    function checkColors(){
            jQuery( jQuery(".imp-shape-container").children('div') ).each(function() {
                room_num = jQuery(this).data('room_num');
                idd = jQuery("#room_num_"+ room_num).val();

                if(idd != undefined){
                    if(idd == 0){
                        jQuery(this).css('background-color','rgba(76, 175, 80, 1)');
                        jQuery(this).css('fill','rgba(76, 175, 80, 1)');
                        jQuery(this).addClass('greenclass');
                    }
                    if(idd == 1){
                        jQuery(this).css('background-color','rgba(183, 28, 28, 1)');
                        jQuery(this).css('fill','rgba(183, 28, 28, 1)');
                        jQuery(this).addClass('redclass');
                    }
                }

    });
```

And the error is as follows

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #room_num_#
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at fa.select (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at Function.fa (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at Function.a.find (autoptimize_db0b5f09817b9858a2c808534bb07b1c.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (autoptimize_db0b5f09817b9858a2c808534bb07b1c.js:2)
    at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
    at new a.fn.init (autoptimize_db0b5f09817b9858a2c808534bb07b1c.js:2)
    at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:1)
```

Saw my own error. Its in the plugin. Sorry for the late response. After asking the question I debugged it again.

Comment: `jQuery(this).data('room_num');` is looking for a `data-room_num=""` attribute - perhaps you mean `jQuery(this).val()`

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor. Post ONLY your script and HTML/CSS - NO PHP since it is completely irrelevant for this question. We want a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably is caused by this line:

```
idd = jQuery("#room_num_"+ room_num).val();
```

I suspect room_num contains a # which creates a wrong id.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code very simple by using generic css class and then do foreach in all items `$('.your_class')` this way your can use `$(this)` object to change style or get value

Answer (score -1):

jquery conflict because jquery not allow to use same id on single page, use each loop with class target.

Thanks

Comment: id="room_num_'.$key.'"  - likely no duplicate

Comment: check with firebug definitely you will find or may be id not ECHO properly... please put your html part and array code.

Comment: It is more likely a lack of data attributes